# How to convert QTime 12 to 24 hr format and viceversa

Tags: c++, qt, qtime

I have `QTime` with current time displayed in screen and the time format I have to change based on selection 12/24. So how I can change the time 12/24 format of `QTime`.

Comment: Isn't that more related to how you format the output, than the actual time which is stored in the `QTime` object? How *do* you display the time in the object? Don't you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: It's depend on how you get it from QTime for example:  `QDateTime dateTime;`  - `dateTime.date().toString("dd.MM.yyyy");` or `dateTime.time().toString("H:mm:ss");`

Comment: Some programmer dude  : Thanks . the time format will be always in 24 hr format . But in output i have to show in 12 hr format or 24 hr format depend on the context .

Comment: A simple `if` check for the "context" and then use the correct format for that "context"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how you get date or time from `QTime`. For example:

```
QDateTime dateTime;
dateTime = dateTime.currentDateTime();
qDebug()<< dateTime.date().toString("dd.MM.yyyy");
qDebug()<< dateTime.time().toString("H:mm:ss");
qDebug()<< dateTime.time().toString("h:mm:ss ap");
```

Output:

```
"03.04.2018"
"15:38:14"
"3:38:14 pm"
```

---

---

@Anonymouse I didn't get your question.  you can get hour, minute, second separatly like this:

```
qDebug()<< dateTime.time().toString("h");
qDebug()<< dateTime.time().toString("mm");
qDebug()<< dateTime.time().toString("ss");
qDebug()<< dateTime.time().toString("ap");
qDebug()<< dateTime.time().toString("h ap");
qDebug()<< dateTime.time().toString("H ap");
```

output:

```
"14"
"12"
"15"
"pm"
"2 pm"
"14 pm"
```

Comment: @Wagmare: did you read the [relevant documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtime.html#toString)?

Comment: Another documentation that provides most of the things you need to know. [Link](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtime.html)

Comment: I wanted the components as seperate strings, so I did this..
    QStringList                   sl;

    sl = now.toString ("h mm AP").split (" ");
    ui->mTimeHour->setText (sl.at (0));
    ui->mTimeMinute->setText (sl.at (1));
    ui->mTimeAMPM->setText (sl.at (2));

[toString ("h") does not return a 12-hour string, it needs the ap\pm to return an hour between 1-12 for PM times]